# How to color rows in excel using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have following part of code:

```
def set_excel(df_list, sheet_list, file_name, columns):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine="openpyxl")
    for dataframe, sheet, columns_list in zip(df_list, sheet_list, columns):
        dataframe.to_excel(
            writer,
            sheet_name=sheet,
            startrow=0,
            startcol=0,
            index=False,
            columns=columns_list,
        )

    writer.save()
```

How can I make color background for every file which will be parsed? I mean, once white color, once blue, once white, one blue and so on.

If this part isn't enough I can upload full code.

Comment: Do you mean a different background color for every sheet in your file? It would definitely help if you added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: X sheets, every sheet would have several files, each files should have other color.